# how to sync two different browsers connected to same react localhost:3000 server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react so I have created a simple app and I open in in two different browsers (IE and chrome). app is runnig on localhost:3000 so I change textbox on chrome and its new value is reflected on chrome now the quistion, is it possible to make this change happen on the IE too? or in other words how can I sync these two browsers so that when data changed on one browser, it also update on the other? I am not using any server currently.
sorry for bad engilsh.

Comment: You'll need some way to communicate between the two, such as a server connected via Web Sockets or even a WebRTC connection (which needs its own server for initial signalling, at least).  From there, look into operational transforms, or decide which end will be the source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply archive what you want with WebSockets. For example, you could take this tutorial ["How to build a React.js chat app in 10 minutes"](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-js-chat-app-in-10-minutes-c9233794642b) or when you prefer video tutorials ["Realtime Node Reactjs with Messenger chat application"](https://hackernoon.com/realtime-node-reactjs-with-messenger-chat-application-97f55e61c74)